# Update UILabel frame and text continously

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, uitouch

I am trying to move uilabel follow my finger using touchMoved. and i am updating current frame to the label text.

label was shuttered but not moving accordingly. if i comment any one like only moving or only updating text its working

Comment: Please add some code to your question!

Comment: Simple i can say like, I am moving my UILabel using UITouch class and simultaneously i am updating text of that label also.. 

Problem: when i am updating continuously(assume it will update 30 times per sec)  and parallely i am updating the label frame.  label was moving but coming back to original position immediately.

@EktaMakadiya

Comment: I’m having the same issue you’re having... different application but I’m sure it’s the same cause. I have a UILabel and a UIButton in my view. Both are not related to each other in any way. I have a UIPanGestureRecognizer attached to the UIButton that allows me to drag it around. Finally, I also have a timer that fires every second and updated the number in the label (it’s a countdown). Every time the timer fires to update the label text, my dragging of the UIButton is cancelled! Same issue, except that mine happens every second, yours happens immediately because you’re updating the label. :(

Answer (score 2):

I made for you a sample where you have a `UILabel` and then you add into it pan gesture recognizer, then you change the frame according to the location in view of the superview for example it's here : `self.view`. Remember to add the `userInteractionEnabled = true` for your `UILabel`. Good luck

```
@IBOutlet var label: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let panGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handlePan(_:)))
    label.addGestureRecognizer(panGestureRecognizer)
    label.userInteractionEnabled = true

}

   func handlePan(gestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    let location = gestureRecognizer.locationInView(self.view)

    var frame = label.frame
    frame.origin.x = location.x
    frame.origin.y = location.y
    label.frame = frame
}
```